# Android : Show Info Constanly

Tags: android, monitoring

I'm working on an app which is run on many tablets in the same network. The app consists of answering questions. There is a server receiving info from these Tablets each time the users answer a question.

What I need to do is to show in a PC screen the info from each Tablet (Serial Number, Question Number...) and to refresh this info every 5 seconds or so. What is the best technology or what I could use to monitor this task?

Comment: Are you looking for a hardware solution? Software? Is this PC the same as the server which the apps are giving their info to? Are you able to modify the server? before we can give any answers, we need much more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you answer questions on tablets and you will want a computer screen to display the results? I would advice you to have an external server (Amazon EC2 for instance) where you have an external database. Each time a question is answered the app makes a call to the server and on the server you will put in the records in the database. Then you only need to build a simple html that fetch the data from the database and display it. A possible framework to do this easy is either [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.com/) or [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo) but there are a lot of them out there. Because I understood this question as very general I can only produce a general answer.

Comment: Yeaah many thanks Simon for these 2 sites. However what I want to show is the current question the user is answering to. Could I send these values from the Tablet to the Server and depending on these values refresh the HTML in some way or another? Or as you said, do I need to create a database?

Comment: Yes that is very much possible and exactly what I thought. The database is really just there for you to keep track what each of the participants answered. You could check out John Doe's answer as well about push notifications but that is limited to local only. An external server and database is needed if you are going to do this world wide or simply not local.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [push notifications](http://elsoufy.blogspot.fr/2012/12/push-notifications-with-parsecom.html),
As you're in a local network you can for instance use a CometD or `WebSocket` server to manage your notifications. For [websocket API](http://elsoufy.blogspot.fr/2012/08/html5-websocket-api.html)